# two parts meta-model in transformation

Tags: emf, eclipse-emf-ecore, model-driven, model-driven-development

My source meta-model has two parts which links together.
When I want to transform an element of second part of this meta-model, it doesn't have error but nothing create in output. What can I do?

[The Metamodel](https://www.4shared.com/folder/-PZLAXRZ/Metamodel.html)

On the other hand how can I merge these ecore metamodels?
[image]

Comment: Could you please provide more details?

Comment: @VladimirVaschenko I have ETL metamodel that uses EOL metamodel. When I want to transform elements of EOL part (in my ATL transformation) I can't.

Comment: Still hard to get a clear picture, so just based on my experience I suppose you may need to check if metamodels are registered with right namespaces in your run-time transformation environment.

Comment: @VladimirVaschenko I attached my metamodel.

Comment: Well, please describe your run-time environment.

Comment: @VladimirVaschenko I use jre7.
as another information, I use eclipse Luna and ATL 3.6.

Comment: how do you run transformation?

Comment: @VladimirVaschenko right click on .atl file, run as, Run configuration. ATL Transformation.
I specify ATL module and input and output Metamodels and input models.
I didn't tick checkbox of Is metamodel in Metamodel part.

Comment: @VladimirVaschenko would you please explain more about "I suppose you may need to check if metamodels are registered with right namespaces in your run-time transformation environment"? how can I check this?

Comment: check this https://wiki.eclipse.org/ATL_3.0.0_New_and_Noteworthy#Register_Metamodel

Comment: @VladimirVaschenko when I do this, it doesn't have generate any output.
it has an error.

Comment: Empty output may means there are no elements conforming to meta-models or no transformation can be applied to them.

Comment: @VladimirVaschenko when I don't register metamodel and transform elements of ETL part, the output is generated. but when I register metamodels, the output is not generated.

Comment: @VladimirVaschenko I have this error:
Error loading platform:/resource/Project/Model/Tree2Graph.etl.model: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.IllegalValueException: Value 'org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.DynamicEObjectImpl@757faad7 (eClass: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.EClassImpl@1c2fa2f9 (name: NameExpression) (instanceClassName: null) (abstract: false, interface: false))' is not legal. (platform:/resource/Project/Model/Tree2Graph.etl.model, 35, 104)

Comment: @VladimirVaschenko the start of my Tree2Graph.etl.model file is like below:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<etl:ETLModule xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:eol="http://www.eclipse.org/epsilon/eol" xmlns:etl="http://www.eclipse.org/epsilon/etl">